# Increment a variable by Simulink

Tags: matlab, increment, simulink

I have a problem in Simulink, I have a variable "k" as constant Block (start Value k =1 ) and i want to increment "k" after each time I click on "the simulation button" untill "k" is 4 then it will be reset to 1 again.

i already try this (see atached Image 1), but in this case k it wil be so long inkremented until the Simulation time is finished (see atached Image 2) and that is not what i want.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbGTC.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzWy7.png)

i will apreciate any Help many thanks Jay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to update the value every time you run the simulation, your best option would be to put some code in the `InitFcn` callback.

This is a (optional) block of code which is run every time the model is initialized. To do this navigate `File > Model Properties > Model Properties`

Select the Callbacks tab, and then the `InitFcn` callback on the left. The following code will check if `k` exists yet in the workspace, and set it if not, and increment it if so. If you put it in the callback, and then set the constant block value to `k` you should get the behavior you want.

```
if ~exist('k', 'var')
    k = 1;
else
    k = k + 1;
end

if k>4
    k = 1;
end
```

Comment: No worries @Sami! Please mark my answer as having worked if it did the trick, so that others with a similar issue know to try it. Thanks

Comment: Nice solution! :)